# AWS EC2 ubuntu Server permission issue

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I  am using 
 `AWS EC2 instance as file instance` and `install ubuntu 14 as os`  and `apche2  as web server`  and **running magento system**

Info1:`i do not create any   apache user group from myself.`

`Info2:`**running a magento system**

`Info3:` **i have no htaccess file**

**Issue1:** File `permission is not work when i am trying using below code step`:
  When  i try to give file and folder permission using below commend it show

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} ;
```

Show error:

```
find: missing argument  to '-exec'
```

[image]

**Issue2:** Apache `mod rewrite is not working`:
try it the code `sudo su -c "a2enmod rewrite"` and by commend check it work.
i have edit on this file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and

```
 ServerName server_domain_name_or_IP
    <Directory /data/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

and `it site goes to 500 Internal error`

**Issue3:** `how to enable htacess`

Please help me anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` should be like this: **`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`**

Also, do not post multiple issues in the same question. Create a separate question for each individual issue.